# Что заменить для того чтобы парсер заработал

Tags: python, html, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get ('https://smart-lab.ru/q/shares/?capitalization_gt=100000000000&capitalization_lt=500000000000')

html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for table in html.select('.simple-little-table'):
    title = el.select('.')
    print(title[0].text)
```

на сайте не классифицируется нужная мне информация[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
мне нужно получить название компании и цену

Answer (score 2):

В следующий раз пишите код, а не скрины. И задачу объясняйте, тут не экстрасенсы. Я написал что-то, не знаю даже, подойдет ли Вам

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get ('https://smart-lab.ru/q/shares/?capitalization_gt=100000000000&capitalization_lt=500000000000')

html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for table in html.select('.simple-little-table'):
    rows = table.findChildren('tr')
    for row in rows[1:]:
        title = row.find_all('td')[2]
        cost = row.find_all('td')[7]
        print(f'Цена компании {title.text} составляет {cost.text} японских попугаев')
```